# How can I run my cron every 2 hours everyday which should starts from 12.30pm?

Tags: cron

I want to run my cron job every 2 hours everyday which starts from 20.13pm. 
Cron should run at 12.30,2.30,4.30 and so on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you more specific ? I don't understand what you mean by "which starts from 20.13pm" in your post and "should start from 20.13" in your title post.

Comment: I want to run my cron job every 2 hours everyday which starts at 20.13pm. The next cron execution will be at 2.30,4.30 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the documentation with `man crontab`.

Here you need to execute your command when minute is 30 so let's start with :

```
30 * * * * * your_command
```

You need to execute you command every 2 hours (actually every multiple of 2) :

```
30 */2 * * * your_command
```

The three last stars from left to right means every day of month, every month and every day of week. So you need to put :

```
30 */2 * * * your_command
```

Comment: Thanks. It makes my day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Crontab Generator](http://www.crontab-generator.org/) for these kinds of headaches

Comment: Thanks for comment.

Comment: I have write my job 0 */2 * * * and I run this at 10.30. It has executed at 12pm not at 12.30pm.  How cron will executed every 2 hours from the given interval(10.30).

Comment: @DevSush Look at my answer please. You need to specify you need you cron to be executed when minute is 30.